# Why is this streamreader objreader not returning any values?

Tags: vb.net, io, streamreader

```
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = ContractDirectory.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo
    Dim CC As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    For Each dra In diar1
        CC = CC + 1
    Next
    Dim Contracts(CC) As Entry
    CC = 0

    For Each dra In diar1

        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Documents\" & dra.Name
        Dim TextLine As String
        Dim Textline2 As String


        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                TextLine = objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
                Textline2 = objReader.ReadLine()
                If (Textline2 = "@#1") Then
                    Contracts(CC).Cnumber = TextLine
                End If

                If (Textline2 = "@#2") Then
                    Contracts(CC).Ctitle = TextLine
                End If

                If (Textline2 = "@#3") Then
                    Contracts(CC).Contype = TextLine
                End If

                If (Textline2 = "@#4") Then
                    Contracts(CC).Cdeadline = TextLine
                End If

                If (Textline2 = "@#5") Then
                    Contracts(CC).Devcategory = TextLine
                End If

                If (Textline2 = "@#6") Then
                    Contracts(CC).Sdesc = TextLine
                End If

                If (Textline2 = "@#7") Then
                    Contracts(CC).Fdesc = TextLine
                End If

                If (Textline2 = "@#8") Then
                    Contracts(CC).Imgid = TextLine
                End If
                CC = CC + 1


            Loop

        Else
            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
        End If

    Next
    TextBox1.Text = Contracts(1).Cnumber
    TextBox2.Text = Contracts(1).Ctitle
    ComboBox1.Text = Contracts(1).Contype
    DateTimePicker1.Text = Contracts(1).Cdeadline
    ComboBox2.Text = Contracts(1).category
    TextBox4.Text = Contracts(1).Sdesc
    TextBox5.Text = Contracts(1).Fdesc
```

I am trying to read the data in many text files into an array. The text file looks like this.

```
Data
@#1
Data
@#2
Data
@#3
Data
@#4
Data
@#5
Data
@#6
```

The text file is full and the @#'s are for sorting into the correct array entry. Can you see anything wrong with it?

UPDATE
So perhaps I don't understand streamreader, does .readline auto go to the next line afterwards. because I thought that was what vbnewline did. but that's for formatting in the variable.

I need it to read the a line then the next and on the loop read the next 2 and so on.
so i could just do it without that loop in a loop if I knew the nextline command or whatever.

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint at TextLine = objReader.ReadLine() and checked what is returned?

Comment: good idea. so it seems to not loop. I think its the Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1

Comment: Do you know an end of file extension i could use instead.

Comment: Pretty iffy code.  The odds that ContractDirectory is not "c:\users\documents" is far too high.  You of course want to use FileInfo.FullPath instead.  The code will die on an NRE, the Contracts array is not initialized.  That should be a List(Of Entry) of course.  Avoid using Peek() by simply checking if StreamReader.ReadLine() returns Nothing.  Appending vbNewLine makes little sense.  And watch out for empty lines, you can't see them at the bottom of the file.

Comment: I have predefined the class for the array. How do I initialise it?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this dumb question. I added this:

```
 For Each dra In diar1
        CC = CC + 1
    Next
    Dim Contracts() As Contract
    ReDim Contracts(CC)
    For c = 0 To CC
        Contracts(c) = New Contract
    Next
```

Cheers guys